# Override the frontend categories controller in cscart

Tags: php, cs-cart

I need to override the categories.php controller in my new addon.

```
`I need to change the Product filters in myaddon.` so override the block files of product filter. But I don't know how to overrite categories.php controller in my addon.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please ask your question with some sort of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the categories.pre.php file in your addon, something like this:

app/addons/newaddon/controllers/frontend/categories.pre.php